# Web API returns description of HttpResponseMessage to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

This code is supposed to result in a file download...

```
public HttpResponseMessage Export()
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StreamContent(stream),
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "myFile.csv"
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");

    return result;
}
```

Instead I get this message...

> {"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume this method is on an `ApiController`?

Comment: [This github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/1507) looks like the thing you're experiencing.  See the comment by tugberkugurlu.

Comment: @Amy Same kind of result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IActionResult Export()
{
    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!");

    var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    return File(stream, "myFile.csv", "text/csv");
}
```